# What's with the NOSCRIPT on the GWO pages?

Tags: google-website-optimizer

Examples in Google's [GWO documentation](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?answer=61144) have `</noscript>` tags floating around free:

```
<h1>
 <script>utmx_section("Headline")</script>
  Welcome!
 </noscript>
</h1>
```

That doesn't even look to me like valid HTML.  Somebody's missing something -- either the example is missing the open `<noscript>` tag or I'm missing the explanation of how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Tag

```
</noscript>
```

let GWO showing only one section at time.

Starting from your code

```
<h1>
<script>utmx_section("Headline")</script>
  Welcome!
</noscript>
</h1>
```

If GWO must hide *Welcome*  content, the generated output become:

```
<h1>
<script>utmx_section("Headline")</script>
 <noscript>
  Welcome!
</noscript>
</h1>
```

The **`<noscript>`** tag is written with a simple **`document.write`** by the **`utmx_section`** function.

In this way the *welcome* content will be hidden because it is wrapped by the **`<noscript></noscript>`**  tag. By the way, if you disable javascript execution of your browser you can view all the contents ( also the hidden contents )

Answer (score 0):

The example isn't wrong, that's how GWO works. In most cases, this is fine, if you run into a case where it breaks something, you can add an opening `<noscript>` right before the closing tag, but after any default content.

http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en-au&answer=64418

Comment: Interesting definition of "works"!  For GWO to function as advertised, I have to specifically defeat the definition of HTML, screw with my page generation, break the validation step of my release process, and rely on clearly faulty behavior in *all* my users' browsers.  @swiders suggestion about the open tag is an excellent one, but the link he supplies suggests it won't work.  Does anybody know?  Also, does anybody know why Google chose to do such a foolish thing?  Grrrr.